Survey data many periods: transformation to current and previous period (wide to long format)
I have a data frame (survey data) called df that looks like this (this is sample data):



respondent_id
r1age
r2age
r3age
r4age
r1smoke
r2smoke
r3smoke
r4smoke
r1income
r2income
r3income
r4income




16178
35
38
41
44
1
1
1
1
60
62
68
70


161719
65
68
71
74
0
0
0
1
50
52
54
56


161720
47
50
53
56
0
1
0
1
80
82
85
87



The number after the "r" or "h" represents the wave or period of each interview. For this particular example, there are only four interviews for each respondent, and data for 3 different variables (age, whether the respondent smokes, and his/her gross annual income in $10,000).
I'm interested in transforming this to get the following instead:



respondent_id
t_1_period
t_age
t_1_age
t_smoke
t_1_smoke
t_income
t_1_income




16178
1
38
35
1
1
62
60


16178
2
41
38
1
1
68
62


16178
3
44
41
1
1
70
68


161719
1
68
65
0
0
52
50


161719
2
71
68
0
0
54
52


161719
3
74
71
1
0
56
54


161720
1
50
47
1
0
82
80


161720
2
53
50
0
1
85
82


161720
3
56
53
1
0
87
85



I'm interested in repeating the respondents such that the number of observations for each respondent are the number of interviews/waves - 1 (that is, the unique transitions), and for each variable there must be t (current period) and t_1 (previous period) columns, again, for each transition. Additionally, I add a t_1_period column representing the number of the previous period for that observation.
I have tried the following:
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["respondent_id"])

variable_names = ["age", "smoke", "income"]

new_rows = []
for respondent_id in df["respondent_id"].unique():
  df_temp = df[df["respondent_id"] == respondent_id]

  for i in range(2, 5):
    new_row = {"respondent_id": respondent_id, "t_1_period": i-1}
    for var in variable_names:
      if var not in ["income"]:
        current_var = f"r{i}{var}"
        previous_var = f"r{i-1}{var}"
        new_row[f"t_{var}"] = df_temp[df_temp["variable"] == current_var]["value"].values[0]
        new_row[f"t_1_{var}"] = df_temp[df_temp["variable"] == previous_var]["value"].values[0]
      elif var == "income":
        current_var = f"h{i}{var}"
        previous_var = f"h{i-1}{var}"
        new_row[f"t_h{var}"] = df_temp[df_temp["variable"] == current_var]["value"].values[0]
        new_row[f"t_1_h{var}"] = df_temp[df_temp["variable"] == previous_var]["value"].values[0]

    new_rows.append(new_row)

df_periods = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)

In my real data, I have much more than 3 variables: I sometimes have up to 100. Additionally, all variables are always present for all periods, however some of them can have NaNs, but the columns are there. In terms of respondents, I can also have a lot: as much as 50,000 for example. Note that some variables start with "h" instead of "r", and others with "s" (not present in this example).
My question: is there a faster way of transforming this? Every time I want to transform the data in this t vs. t-1 version for all variables I decide to include in variable_names I have to wait a lot. I believe there must be a better way of doing this. I appreciate your help, thank you.

There are many ways to approach that, wide_to_long is an option but you would need to pre-process the column names (it expects the stubnames as prefixes, not suffixes).
I'd suggest to use a MultiIndex and stack, here is an example that doesn't require to know the stubnames:
# set aside respondent_id and create a MultiIndex
tmp = df.set_index('respondent_id')
tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp.columns.str.extract(r'[rh](\d+)(\D+)'),
                                       names=['t_1_period', None])

# reshape
tmp = tmp.stack(0, future_stack=True)

# concatenate the long format with a shifted version of itself
out = (pd.concat([tmp.groupby(level=0).shift(-1), tmp], keys=['t', 't_1'], axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
      )

# flatten MultiIndex
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
out.reset_index(inplace=True)

# remove the last value per group
out = out[out['respondent_id'].duplicated(keep='last')].convert_dtypes()

Output:
    respondent_id t_1_period  t_age  t_1_age  t_income  t_1_income  t_smoke  t_1_smoke
0           16178          1     38       35        62          60        1          1
1           16178          2     41       38        68          62        1          1
2           16178          3     44       41        70          68        1          1
4          161719          1     68       65        52          50        0          0
5          161719          2     71       68        54          52        0          0
6          161719          3     74       71        56          54        1          0
8          161720          1     50       47        82          80        1          0
9          161720          2     53       50        85          82        0          1
10         161720          3     56       53        87          85        1          0


Nice and compact.

t_1_age, t_1_income, and t_1_smoke columns' values are not as requested

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi you're right, I missed that. Thanks a lot. It's actually easier this way.  See update ;)

one more thing, I think you should replace extract(r'r(\d+)(\D+)') with extract(r'a-zA-Z(\D+)') because it is not sure what latter will be used.

I used [rh](\d+)(\D+) since OP mentioned r and h as prefixes, but of course this can be tweaked

Thank you @mozway I had to research a bit on my side though to find an alternative to the future_stack parameter of DataFram.stack() (still apparently not supported on Google Colab: they have pandas version 2.0.3 (less than 2.1))

Then you can probably ignore this parameter here

Yes, for anyone who reads this in the future: I just removed the future_stack parameter and added drop_na=False instead. Also, had to make sure that the first column of tmp.columns.str.extract(r'[rhs](\d+)(\D+)') is indeed int or float (instead of string) just so that out.reset_index(drop=True) work well at the very end, which I also added, as sometimes when there are more than 10 periods, the index is sorted instead like "1, 10, ..." when it should be "1, 2, ..."

One option is with a for loop, with some help from itertools pairwise:
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor # not necessary, used here for relocation of columns
from itertools import pairwise
temp = df.set_index('respondent_id')
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(r"(\d)",expand=True)
temp.columns.names = ['letter','number','dimension']
temp = temp.reorder_levels(order=['dimension','number','letter'],axis=1)
uniqs=temp.columns.get_level_values('dimension').unique()
temp = temp.droplevel(level='letter',axis=1)
box = []
for label in uniqs:
    ff = temp[label]
    columns = ff.columns[::-1]
    columns = pairwise(columns)

    ff = [ff.loc[:, col]
            .set_axis([f"t_{label}", f"t_1_{label}"],axis=1)
            .assign(t_1_period=col[-1]) 
          for col in columns]
    box.append(ff)
# column assignment/creation in Pandas is relatively cheap 
# - code here can be adapted to deal with more labels/dataframes.
boxx=[f1.assign(**f2).assign(**f3) for f1, f2, f3 in zip(*box)]

(pd.concat(boxx)
.sort_values(['respondent_id', 't_1_period'])
.move('t_1_period',axis=1) # from pyjanitor, you can ignore this, and move manually
.reset_index() # you can ignore this, Index gives you extra powers
)
   respondent_id t_1_period  t_age  t_1_age  t_smoke  t_1_smoke  t_income  t_1_income
0          16178          1     38       35        1          1        62          60
1          16178          2     41       38        1          1        68          62
2          16178          3     44       41        1          1        70          68
3         161719          1     68       65        0          0        52          50
4         161719          2     71       68        0          0        54          52
5         161719          3     74       71        1          0        56          54
6         161720          1     50       47        1          0        82          80
7         161720          2     53       50        0          1        85          82
8         161720          3     56       53        1          0        87          85

Another option, based on @mozway's logic is to reshape into long form, shift upwards and concatenate:
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
t1=df.pivot_longer(index='respondent_id', 
                   #.value determines which part of the columns
                   # remains as a header
                   names_to=['t_1_period', '.value'], 
                   names_pattern=r".(\d)(.+)",
                   sort_by_appearance=True)
# shift upwards on the groupby
t2=t1.groupby('respondent_id',sort=False).shift(-1)
booleans=t2.isna().all(axis=1)
t1=(t1
    .loc[~booleans]
    .rename(columns={'age':'t1_age',
                     'smoke':'t1_smoke',
                     'income':'t1_income'})
   )
t2=(t2
    .loc[~booleans]
    .drop(columns='t_1_period')
    .add_prefix('t_')
    )
(pd
.concat([t1,t2],axis=1)
.loc[:, ['respondent_id', 't_1_period',
         't_age','t1_age',
         't_smoke','t1_smoke',
         't_income','t1_income']]
.astype(int)
    respondent_id  t_1_period  t_age  t1_age  t_smoke  t1_smoke  t_income  t1_income
0           16178           1     38      35        1         1        62         60
1           16178           2     41      38        1         1        68         62
2           16178           3     44      41        1         1        70         68
4          161719           1     68      65        0         0        52         50
5          161719           2     71      68        0         0        54         52
6          161719           3     74      71        1         0        56         54
8          161720           1     50      47        1         0        82         80
9          161720           2     53      50        0         1        85         82
10         161720           3     56      53        1         0        87         85


That's nice, but what if there are more than 4 periods in data?

it should be adaptable. I dont know the full details of your data, so cant really say

One way is to avoid loops if you have many features:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "respondent_id": [16178, 161719, 161720],
    "r1age": [35, 65, 47], "r2age": [38, 68, 50], "r3age": [41, 71, 53], "r4age": [44, 74, 56],
    "r1smoke": [1, 0, 0], "r2smoke": [1, 0, 1], "r3smoke": [1, 0, 0], "r4smoke": [1, 1, 1],
    "r1income": [60, 50, 80], "r2income": [62, 52, 82], "r3income": [68, 54, 85], "r4income": [70, 56, 87]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["respondent_id"], var_name="variable", value_name="value")
print("Melted DataFrame:\n", df_long.head())

df_long['period'] = df_long['variable'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
df_long['variable'] = df_long['variable'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+)')
print("DataFrame after extracting period and variable:\n", df_long.head())

df_wide = df_long.pivot_table(index=['respondent_id', 'period'], columns='variable', values='value').reset_index()
print("Pivoted DataFrame:\n", df_wide.head())

df_t = df_wide.copy()
df_t_minus_1 = df_wide.copy()
df_t_minus_1['period'] += 1
print("DataFrame t:\n", df_t.head())
print("DataFrame t-1:\n", df_t_minus_1.head())

df_merged = pd.merge(df_t, df_t_minus_1, on=['respondent_id', 'period'], suffixes=('', '_t_1'))
print("Merged DataFrame:\n", df_merged.head())

df_merged = df_merged.rename(columns={
    'period': 't_1_period',
    'age': 't_age', 'age_t_1': 't_1_age',
    'smoke': 't_smoke', 'smoke_t_1': 't_1_smoke',
    'income': 't_income', 'income_t_1': 't_1_income'
})
print("Columns after renaming:\n", df_merged.head())

df_final = df_merged[df_merged['t_1_period'] > 1].copy()
df_final['t_1_period'] -= 1
print("Filtered DataFrame:\n", df_final.head())

df_final = df_final[['respondent_id', 't_1_period', 't_age', 't_1_age', 't_smoke', 't_1_smoke', 't_income', 't_1_income']]


print(df_final)


With gives
Melted DataFrame:
    respondent_id variable  value
0          16178    r1age     35
1         161719    r1age     65
2         161720    r1age     47
3          16178    r2age     38
4         161719    r2age     68
DataFrame after extracting period and variable:
    respondent_id variable  value  period
0          16178      age     35       1
1         161719      age     65       1
2         161720      age     47       1
3          16178      age     38       2
4         161719      age     68       2
Pivoted DataFrame:
 variable  respondent_id  period   age  income  smoke
0                 16178       1  35.0    60.0    1.0
1                 16178       2  38.0    62.0    1.0
2                 16178       3  41.0    68.0    1.0
3                 16178       4  44.0    70.0    1.0
4                161719       1  65.0    50.0    0.0
DataFrame t:
 variable  respondent_id  period   age  income  smoke
0                 16178       1  35.0    60.0    1.0
1                 16178       2  38.0    62.0    1.0
...
5             56.0        54.0  
6             82.0        80.0  
7             85.0        82.0  
8             87.0        85.0 

where the last dataframe is the df you expected.

Another solution relying on concat and melt. There might be an easier way to assign the prefixes directly during concatenation.
column_names = list(dict.fromkeys(([i for i in df.set_index('respondent_id').columns.str.replace('r\d','', regex=True)])).keys())

out = df.set_index('respondent_id').groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.concat([
pd.melt(x, value_vars=[i for i in x.columns if j in i], value_name=j).drop(columns='variable') for j in column_names
],axis=1 ) ).droplevel(1)

out = out.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x, x.shift()], axis=1, ) ).dropna(axis=0, how='any')

out.columns = list('t_'+out.columns[::2]) + list('t_1_'+out.columns[1::2])
out = out.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[-1])

Output:
                 t_age  t_1_age  t_income  t_1_income  t_smoke  t_1_smoke
  respondent_id                                                          
0 16178             38      1.0         1        60.0       62       35.0
  16178             41      1.0         1        62.0       68       38.0
  16178             44      1.0         1        68.0       70       41.0
1 161719            68      0.0         0        50.0       52       65.0
  161719            71      0.0         0        52.0       54       68.0
  161719            74      0.0         1        54.0       56       71.0
2 161720            50      0.0         1        80.0       82       47.0
  161720            53      1.0         0        82.0       85       50.0
  161720            56      0.0         1        85.0       87       53.0

